# Need to change windows workflow activity property hint text

Tags: workflow-foundation

I need to change the custom activity properties hint text instead of "Enter a VB Expression" to some thing more descriptive.

Is there any option to change hint text?

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve this by using the `[Description("descriptive text")]` attribute.